# Proving that $L= \{a^nb^n, n\ge 0\}$ is not a regular language.

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The questions i'm 'stuck' on is: Let $\Sigma = \{0,1,2\}$ be the alphabet, and let $L$ be the collection of all the languages that contains only words that have even length. Prove that there are languages in $L$ that are not regular.

So the way i looked at this question in by searching an iregular language, That still stands in the conditions of $L$. Then I saw this language $L_1=\{a^nb^n \mid  n\ge0\}$ as an example of a nonregular language. But it didn't have any explanation. [Except that fact I actually couldn't find a regular expression for that one].

How can i actually prove that something isn't a regular language?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean $b^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma) and show that you can't pump any word of the form $a^nb^n$ for any $n$.